# Word JS API: Word.Paragraph.getTextRanges() not working in texts with hyperlinks

Tags: ms-word, hyperlink, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

In my word add-in I'd like to select a certain word in a given paragraph by its index start position. So I created a highlightWordByIndex function, which works fine unless there's a hyperlink somewhere in the text.

The error happens when I call `paragraph.getTextRanges()` at a text containing hyperlinks: The endingMarks parameter is correct and I expect to get the proper items (separated by endingMarks), which I can then select. But the returned text ranges are messed up. If I remove the hyperlink it works fine again.

Is it not plain text that is being returned when calling `textRanges.load('text')`?
Unfortunately I can't find anything related in the add-ins documentation.

Here's the function:

```
export const highlightWordByIndex = async (start: number, length: number) => {
  await Word.run(async (context) => {
    const selectIssue = async (
      paragraph: Word.Paragraph,
      endingMarks: string[],
      index: number
    ) => {
      const textRanges = paragraph.getTextRanges(endingMarks, true)
      textRanges.load('text')
      await context.sync()
      textRanges.items[index].select()
    }

    const selectedParagraph = context.document
      .getSelection()
      .paragraphs.getFirst()
    selectedParagraph.load('text')
    await context.sync()

    const preSelect = selectedParagraph.text.substring(0, start)
    const select = selectedParagraph.text.substring(start, start + length)
    const postSelect = selectedParagraph.text.substring(start + length)

    if (preSelect.length && postSelect.length) {
      await selectIssue(selectedParagraph, [preSelect, select, postSelect], 1)
    } else if (preSelect.length) {
      await selectIssue(selectedParagraph, [preSelect, select], 1)
    } else {
      await selectIssue(selectedParagraph, [select, postSelect], 0)
    }
  })
}
```

Maybe there's a better way to select words by their start index, which also includes hyperlinks inside the text?

UPDATE:
I changed the code to take use of the Word.Paragraph.search() function which works fine so far regardless of occurring hyperlinks etc.
It takes the word and its start position in the current paragraph:

```
export const highlightWordByContent = async (word: string, start: number) => {
  await Word.run(async (context) => {
    const selectedParagraph = context.document
      .getSelection()
      .paragraphs.getFirst()
    selectedParagraph.load('text')
    await context.sync()

    const words = selectedParagraph.text.split(' ')
    let startIndexOfCurrentWord = 0,
      countOfFoundWords = 0,
      selectIndex = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      if (words[i] === word) {
        countOfFoundWords++
        if (start === startIndexOfCurrentWord) {
          selectIndex = countOfFoundWords
          selectIndex--
        }
      }
      startIndexOfCurrentWord += words[i].length + 1
    }

    const wordsToSelectAsRange = selectedParagraph.search(word)
    wordsToSelectAsRange.load('text')
    await context.sync()

    wordsToSelectAsRange.items[selectIndex].select()
  })
}
```

Still, I don't think that's the way how to do this properly. There's way too much index counting and it feels like a hack instead of proper use of the Word.js api.

So any improvements are appreciated.

Comment: It's not obvious to me how to fix this as I'm just not that familiar with the word.js API, but AFAICS it's not just hyperlinks, it could be any field code in there. So suppose you have a para. like "The { SEQ x }quick brown fox jumps", you update the { SEQ } field, and you specify start = 1 and length = 10, preSelect will be "T", select will be "he 1quick " and postSelect will be "brown fox jumps". Your code will call the 1st branch of the if, but it will not find the *select* text because the plain text "he 1quick " does not match the rich text where the 1 is actually a SEQ field.

Comment: Yeah you seem to be right @jonsson - although textRanges.load(text) delivers the correct string, the ranges underneath the hood are what I'm really after. Maybe someone can clarify how to achieve this.

Honestly I don't really get why `paragraph.getTextRanges()` returns such broken ranges when the text contains links or other fields. That's not what the function name suggests.

Comment: Looks like the search method is doing what you need, anyway. Re. getTextRanges I get the impression it's really for use with much simpler delimiters (spaces, tabs, commas, etc. ) and situations. But then the coder has to *know* that's what they are dealing with...